# Add leading zero to numbers

Tags: string, vbscript, formatting, numbers

I, need get values like 05:00, -05:00 ,when on input have number values 5, -5..If on input values like 10,-12 then don't need adding leading zeros..I can create some function which check how many digits have number and then add if needed "0" char, but maybe anyone have finest decision?

Comment: Just to get this sorted out: Does the desired output represent a HH:mm format?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can find to help with this is the FormatNumber function in VBScript.  W3 has a good example and test tool here: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatnumber.asp

You will most likely have to wrap this function to handle your specific case of appending a 0.  This should be pretty simple though, simply do an IFTHEN statement sort of like:

```
IF x > 0 & x < 10 THEN "0" + x
ELSEIF x > -10 & x < 0 THEN "-0" + Abs(x)
```

Or something of that nature.  Again this would have to be a string formatting thing as the integer will always reflect 5 or -5 not 05 or -05

Hope that helps

Comment: this would yield "0-5" for -5

Comment: Good catch, i'm supplying pseudo code here, but I've updated it to handle the negative numbers properly now.

Comment: ToString is no vbscript, Abs(x) isn't even an object

Comment: @peter it's psuedo code! And Abs is a VBScript function: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_abs.asp

Comment: @Brent, i know it's pseudocode but you suggest to someone who's skills in vbs are unknown that abs(x) is something that is an object and that you can convert it to string by using the ToString method of it, totally not VbScript..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Function FormatHour (input)
    Dim sign
    If (input < 0) Then
        sign = "-"
    End If

    FormatHour = sign & FormatDateTime(TimeSerial(Abs(input), 0, 0), vbShortTime)
End Function
```

Comment: why are you assuming it's a date/time?  The post is flagged as Numbers not Date or Time problems, so if for some reason it's not a time this solution doesn't work.  Moreover, I've never seen a negative time before like this, is there a special country format I'm not aware of?

Comment: Because 05:00 doesn't look like a number but rather an hour:minute representation. Anyway using FormatDateTime gives you the desired format without too much concatenating ;-)

Comment: Yea it does appear that way, just going with what the OP provided. I'd be curious if they say it is time, not sure why you would need a negative time.  Thanks for posting the comment to the OP though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this lpad and rpad example from Microsoft?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96458

Comment: The example doesn't handle negative input - just padding is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Alexey, next time please publish what you've got, now we have to guess what you really want, so here is my guess

```
a = array(0, 5, -5, 15, -55) 
for each e in a 
  wscript.echo mid(" -",instr(e,"-")+1,1)&right("0"&abs(e),2)&":00" 
next    

 00:00
 05:00
-05:00
 15:00
-55:00
```

OR

```
for i = 0 to uBound(a) 
  a(i) = mid(" -",instr(a(i),"-")+1,1)&right("0"&abs(a(i)),2)&":00" 
next 
wscript.echo join(a,",")  
'00:00, 05:00,-05:00, 15:00,-55:00
```

Comment: returns "000:00" for e == 0, because Sgn(0) => 0.

Comment: Are you maybe mixing me up with Alexey? My answer contains everything there is ... plus the assumption that Alexey actually deals with an HH:mm picture format.

Comment: @Filburt, you're right, sorry for the mixup, edited my answer to deal with the 0 value and to get justification right along